# Class as Return Type in Bison: Where to define the class?

Tags: c++, bison

I've found three tutorials that cover writing a parser in C++ using Bison: [here](http://ds9a.nl/lex-yacc/cvs/lex-yacc-howto.html), [here](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html), and [here](http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/). The first two don't cover how to use a class as the return type of a rule. The third does cover it, but it doesn't appear to clearly explain the stipulations.

Here is a simple parser.yy file which uses a class in this manner.

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>

extern FILE * yyin; 
int yyerror(char *s) 
{
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("error\n");
}

int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}

int yyparse() { return 1; }

int main() { 
    yyparse(); 
    return 1;  
}

class myclass { int x; };

%}

%union {
    int token;
    myclass * mc; 
}

%token <token> REGISTER  
%type <mc> start_sym

%start start_sym

%%

start_sym :
     REGISTER '+' { $$ = new myclass(); }
    ;
```

Bison runs with no problems using this input. I defined a simple input for flex to use with this. However, when I try to compile it, I get the error:

```
$ g++ parser.tab.cc lex.yy.cc

In file included from lex.ll:11:0:
parser.yy:31:5: error: ‘myclass’ does not name a type
     myclass * mc;
     ^
```

Where is the appropriate place to declare myclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming from your lex-generated file, and is the result of your not putting a definition for you class in a place where the lex-generated file can see it. Putting the definition in a separate header file and including that header file in both the scanner (flex) and parser (bison) files is the simplest solution; moreover, it makes sense because there are probably other compilation units -- the consumer of the parse -- which also require these headers.

If you are using a relatively modern version of bison, for the case of type definitions which really only need to be visible to the scanner and parser, and no other component, it is possible to get bison to insert definitions into the header file which it generates by putting a `%code requires` block into your prologue:

```
%code requires {
   class myclass {
     // ...
   };
}
```

(You can also use a `%code provides` block, but normally you would want these definitions to be available when the semantic type union is defined, which is the location of `%code requires`.)

For more information, see the [bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#g_t_0025code-Summary).

With respect to the `extern "C"` issue, I would have thought that to be unnecessary if you include the flex-generated header file in your bison input. You also might want to specify `%option noyywrap` in your flex input, unless you are actually using `yywrap`. The `yywrap` included in `-lfl` has `"C"` linkage, but as far as I know the `extern "C" yywrap` declaration does occur in the flex-generated header file.

Having said all that, I need to confess that I don't use the C++ APIs for either bison or flex. I prefer to just use the C interfaces; the resulting files can be compiled cleanly with a C++ compiler (at least with recent versions of the bison and flex tools), and you can use pointers to C++ objects in your semantic union without problems.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the only place that I can declare the class without getting a compilation error is in a separate header file ("myclass.h"). This header file must be included in both parser.yy and scanner.ll. In scanner.ll, it must be included before parser.tab.hh.

Additionally, the only way I've gotten it to compile without the compiler complaining about yyparse(), yylex(), or yywrap() is to include prototypes for these functions in the file myclass.h with external C linkage, like so:

```
#ifndef __MYCLASS_H_
#define __MYCLASS_H_

class myclass { int x; };

extern "C" {
int yyparse(void);
int yylex(void);
int yywrap(void);
}

#endif
```

If anyone is aware of a better solution, please do let me know.

Comment: This is what I do.  Except I redefine the union into a struct that can then contain classes (strings, smart pointers).  This can be done by redefining YYSTYPE.  This also must be done in a header file.